# if Statement example help JAVA

Tags: java, if-statement

I am currently reading the OCA Java SE 7 Programmer I Study Guide and I need help understanding an example. Here is the code:

```
boolean b;
    boolean bValue = (b = true);
    //Evaluates to true

    if(bValue)
        System.out.println("TRUE");
    else
        System.out.println("FALSE");

    if (bValue = false)
        System.out.println("TRUE");
    else
        System.out.println("FALSE");

    if(bValue == false)
        System.out.println("TRUE");
    else
        System.out.println("FALSE");
```

Where I am having problems with this code is the second output. Why is it false and not true?
Is it a case of bValue is now false and therefore doesn't satisfy the if meaning that it displays "FALSE"?

EDIT: I know the difference between  = and ==. What I don't understand is shouldn't it print "TRUE"?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I know the difference between = and ==. = is Assignment and == is equals...

Comment: Good luck on your exam.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The assignment `bValue = false` calls an operator method for equals. The equals operator returns the right-hand value. This is so that equals operators can be chained:

```
boolean foo;
boolean bar;
foo = bar = false;
```

In `bValue = false`, the result of the equals operator is what's actually being evaluated, so it's false.

Answer (score 7):

Because in this line:

```
if (bValue = false)
```

you are **assigning** the value `false` to `bValue`, and the result of the expression is `false`.

Answer (score 2):

It evaluates to `false` because the = operator is used, not the `==`.  In other words, the second `if` statement assign the value `false` to the variable bValue.

Answer (score 0):

You're *assigning* with false, not *comparing* wit false.

This is why you should code it as :

```
if (!bValue)
```

and why what you have is an anti pattern.